# Screen is scrolling left automatically in Internet Explorer Browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver

While testing in selenium , Screen is automatically scrolling to left in IE Browser. The same is working fine in Chrome Browser. In HTML code the developer uses the **sections**.
 Is it the functionality of development side, so that the screen is moving to left. Or is there any solution we can manage it through selenium Webdriver?

Comment: Ok. Interesting information... any questions?

Comment: facing same issue, is there a solution for this  ? Kindly help if you have resolved this

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with IE8 to my knowledge. I had this "work around" *hack*.

```
     JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
     js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(-195,0)", "");
```

Comment: But I am facing this issue on IE 11